# How do I make an offline recovery USB for MacOS Monterey?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup, recovery, monterey

I have a Macbook Pro from 2015 with a MacOS Monterey 12.6

I want to make a recovery USB for it

I tried following instructions here, https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-12-beta-usb-drive-in-5-min/
but after I clicked update now as mentioned in its step 1, and after waiting for about 30 seconds, I did not see any "Install MacOS Monterey" file in the Applications folder. Since this step did not work I have not tried the "Install InstallAssistant.pkg" method mentioned in its step 3.

I also found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgHyvj_nWCU which says to search for the MacOS Monterey installer in the App store, but when I search for monterey I don't see the installer in the result either. I can't find the official apple link for a recovery USB iso either.

Could someone explain or point me to a tutorial on how to make an offline bootable MacOS Monterey USB recovery drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command below to list which versions of macOS full installers are available to download on your Mac.

```
softwareupdate --list-full-installers
```

> Note: This list only includes versions of macOS that Apple will allow you to download *to your Mac*. The actual list available downloads is probably longer.

Monterey should appear in the list at least once. You can use `softwareupdate` to download a listed version of macOS. For example, if macOS Monterey 12.6.3 is shown, then command below would download this release.

```
softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 12.6.3
```

You can get more information by entering the command below.

```
softwareupdate --help
```

---

The steps below were taken from the Apple website [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

1. Format as Mac OS Extended a 16 GB or larger USB flash drive. Use the name `MyVolume`.
2. Enter the command below.

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are here.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

There are no ISO's, of course.  There never have been.

Comment: Better if you can precis the instructions contained in the link; otherwise if the link goes dead [which Apple KB links do frequently] then there's no answer left.